# PHP: file_get_contents crashing php on broken image links

Tags: php

I am trying to do something very simple with PHP - just include (and run) another PHP file, and hold the results in a variable for use in a view.  However I've found if I have `img` tags, where the image doesn't exist, PHP hangs for ~30 seconds, and sometimes even crashes!

Is there a way to include another file to a variable, which PHP likes better than this?

index.php

```
<?php $content = file_get_contents($file); ?>

<?php if(in_array($i, $noScroll)) : ?>
    <div class="content">
        <?= $content; ?>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="content scroller">
        <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="viewport">
            <div class="overview">
                <?= $content; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

file.php

```
<ul class="thumbs">
    <li><div><a href="#"><img src="assets/card/figure8.jpg"/></a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#"><img src="assets/card/pathfinder.jpg"/></a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is `$i` and `$noScroll` here?

Comment: i didn't add it as it doesn't affect the question. `$i` is the index of a loop, `$noScroll = [2, 5]`, i left in the functionality to show why I'm not just using `include`

Comment: you would have simply added `include("file.php");`, why `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Not possible to answer the question with the given pieces of information. Are you including a PHP file with `file_get_contents`? Simply require/include it.. but more important what is `$content`?

Comment: i'd like to assign the file contents to a variable for a fairly complex view.  this is a reduced case.

Comment: is there really no way to assign a PHP template to a variable without strange issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not PHP, but your system.

While trying to access files through network, it has a network access timeout. So, if file does not exist, or event is not reachable (permission denied, infinite redirection and so on...) it will wait until the network timeout is reached (or PHP timeout, the sortest one will be the winner).

All of that is normal. You just shouldn't try to access distant files, or reduce timeouts. You may also use file_exists and is_readable functions to get rid of access timeouts, through network or local filesystem as well.

Comment: Is there a way to assign file contents to a variable which does not try to load images, but just returns the generated HTML/PHP?